# Given a local diffeomorphism $f: N \to M$ with $M$ orientable, then $N$ is orientable.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Given a local diffeomorphism $f: N \to M$ with $M$ orientable.  Why is $N$ orientable?  My professor wrote this in class without giving a proof and said "you should try to prove this for fun :)".  I am clueless, please help :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you know about the connection between differential forms and orientability? That $M$ is orientable means precisely that $M$ has a non-vanishing volume form $\omega$. To show $N$ is orientable, we must show $N$ also admits a non-vanishing volume form. It seems natural to consider the pullback of $\omega$, and you can check directly that it is non-vanishing at each point because $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: All right that is quite helpful.  I am now trying to show that $f^* \omega$ is non-vanishing.  During this process I am examining the determinant of Df.  I can tell that this determinant must be not be zero since f is local diffeo.  However, I do not follow why?

Comment: Actually, I think I got that now.  If the determinant was zero, then Df would not be invertible which means f could not be a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @LeoSpencer Precisely.