# The pullback orientation on $M$ induced by a local diffeomorphism $F:M\to N$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'd like to understand the proof of the following proposition, cited from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

> **Proposition 15.15 (The Pullback Orientation).** *Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary. If $F:M\to N$ is a local diffeomorphism and $N$ is oriented, then $M$ has a unique orientation, called the **pullback orientation induced by $F$**, such that $F$ is orientation-preserving.*
>
> *Proof.* For each $p\in M$, there is a unique orientation on $T_p M$ that makes the isomorphism $dF_p:T_p M\to T_{F(p)}N$ orientation-preserving. This defines a pointwise orientation on $M$ ...

**Why does there exist a unique orientation on $T_p M$ that makes the isomorphism $dF_p:T_p M\to T_{F(p)}N$ orientation-preserving?**

Since $dF_p$ is an isomorphism, it must carry a basis for $T_p M$ to a basis for $T_{F(p)}N$. But, this is not enough. To show $dF_p$ is orientation-preserving, one must equip $T_p M$ with a choice of orientations (keep in mind that $T_p M$ is not oriented initially) and prove that $dF_p$ carries a positively-oriented basis to a positively-oriented basis, where I have been stuck.

I think the question can be taken care of properly by appealing to linear algebra, but somehow I don't know how to start it. Can anyone give me a piece of advice? If possible, please do not refer to any differential forms. Thank you.

**Note.** Two bases for a vector space are said to be *consistently oriented* if the change-of-coordinate matrix between them has positive determinant. Being consistently oriented characterizes an equivalence relation on bases, and we define an orientation on a vector space to be an equivalence class of bases.

Comment: Aren't there only two orientations on $T_pM$, one of which is taken to the given orientation of $T_{F(p)}N$ and one which is not (according to whether the determinant of $dF_p$ is positive or negative)?

Comment: An isomorphism between oriented vector spaces is either orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing.

Comment: What about the pullback of a positively oriented basis for $T_{F(p)}N$? This also preserves the equivalence relation that defines the orientation.

Comment: @YiFan Thank you, but it seems to make no sense to talk about the determinant of $dF_p$. After all, $dF_p$ is not a linear operator on a vector space.

Comment: @Steve $T_pM$ can be considered a real vector space whose basis consists of the tangent vectors. Although, to be fair, I realized I was being rather imprecise in my statement. It should really depend on the determinant of the change-of-coordinates transformation between the image of some basis of $T_pM$ under $dF_p$ and the positively-oriented basis of $T_{F(p)}N$.

Comment: @Steve you're wrong on that one. $\mathrm{d}F_p$ is indeed a linear operator between vectors spaces.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Thank you. What I did mean is that $dF_p$ is NOT a linear transformation from $T_p M$ to $\mathbf{T_p M}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a linear algebra problem. Let $(W, \mathcal{O})$ be an oriented vector space and $T\colon V \to W$ an isomorphism. We know that $T$ takes bases of $V$ to bases of $W$. If $\mathfrak{v} = (v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ is a basis for $V$, write $T\mathfrak{v}$ for the basis $(Tv_1,\ldots,Tv_n)$ of $W$.   Then just set $$T^*\mathcal{O} = \{ \mathfrak{v} \mid \mathfrak{v}\mbox{ is a basis for $V$ with $T\mathfrak{v}\in\mathcal{O}$}\}. $$This notation clearly justifies the name "pull-back orientation" and makes $T$ orientation-preserving by design. It is indeed an orientation, because each basis for $W$ is either in $\mathcal{O}$ or $-\mathcal{O}$, so each basis for $V$ is either in $T^*\mathcal{O}$ or in $T^*(-\mathcal{O})$; "uniqueness" then says that the expected relation $T^*(-\mathcal{O}) = -T^*\mathcal{O}$ holds.

Now, saying that $N$ is a oriented manifold is the same as saying that for each $y\in N$ there is an orientation $\mathcal{O}_y$ for $T_yN$, and that the assignment $y\mapsto \mathcal{O}_y$ is, suitably understood, smooth.

If $F\colon M\to N$ is a local diffeomorphism, then each ${\rm d}F_x\colon T_xM\to T_{F(x)}N$ is an isomorphism, so we have an orientation $({\rm d}F_x)^*(\mathcal{O}_{F(x)})$ on $T_xM$. The assignment $x\mapsto ({\rm d}F_x)^*(\mathcal{O}_{F(x)})$ is also smooth because $F$ is a local diffeomorphism (smoothness is a local notion, so requiring $F$ to be a global diffeomorphism is overkill).

Comment: Is there a typo in the first paragraph? It doesn't make sense to apply $T$ to each $w_i$ since those live in the target space $W$.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed things. I was half asleep when writing it, wasn't sure if I was going to use $V$ for domain or codomain and changed my mind halfway through, a mess. It should look good now

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if my answer is a duplicate of that by @Ivo Terek, but the notation $T^*$ is really Greek to me. Anyway, thanks for his/her kindly help, and I'd like to present a solution that is based on the idea of @Ivin Babu.

By hypothesis, an equivalence class $[\beta]$ of bases has been designated as the orientation of $T_{F(p)}N$. With the aid of $[\beta]$, $T_p M$ can now be endowed with the orientation $[(dF_p)^{-1}(\beta)]$. To make sure the orientation $[(dF_p)^{-1}(\beta)]$ is well-defined, pick another basis $\gamma$ in $[\beta]$ and show that
$$[(dF_p)^{-1}(\gamma)]=[(dF_p)^{-1}(\beta)].$$
All we have to do is show that $(dF_p)^{-1}(\gamma)$ and $(dF_p)^{-1}(\beta)$ are *consistently oriented* (see the note). If you grab a book on linear algebra and review the section regarding change-of-coordinate matrices, you will see
$$[(dF_p)^{-1}]_\gamma^{(dF_p)^{-1}\ (\gamma)}=\left([I_{T_p M}]_{(dF_p)^{-1}\ (\gamma)}^{(dF_p)^{-1}\ (\beta)}\right)^{-1}[(dF_p)^{-1}]_\beta^{(dF_p)^{-1}\ (\beta)}[I_{T_{F(p)}\ N}]_\gamma^\beta,$$
where $I_{T_p M}$ is the identity operator on $T_p M$, and so on. Watch closely and conclude that the matrix representations of $(dF_p)^{-1}$ are the identity matrices. Now take the determinants, and you will see
$$\det\left([I_{T_p M}]_{(dF_p)^{-1}\ (\gamma)}^{(dF_p)^{-1}\ (\beta)}\right)=\det\left([I_{T_{F(p)}\ N}]_\gamma^\beta\right)>0.$$
The last inequality holds because $\gamma\in[\beta]$.

After testifying the orientation is well-defined, we need to show that $dF_p$ is orientation-preserving, that is, prove that $\forall\alpha\in[(dF_p)^{-1}(\beta)]$, $dF_p(\alpha)\in[\beta]$. By the same argument in the previous step, you can prove that
$$[dF_p(\alpha)]=[dF_p((dF_p)^{-1}(\beta))]=[\beta],$$
which implies $dF_p(\alpha)\in[\beta]$. The differential of $F$ at $p$ indeed preserves orientation of bases.

**Epilog.** To address the uniqueness problem, one can observe that if $T_p M$ is instead oriented by the equivalence class of $\alpha\notin[(dF_p)^{-1}(\beta)]$, $dF_p$ will become *orientation-reversing*.

Comment: Regarding $T^*$, you could have used it to avoid a lot of keystrokes: Denoting $T = DF_p$, one defines $$T^*[\beta] = [(dF_p)^{-1}(\beta)]$$